# How to set hit counter in yii

Tags: php, yii

I'd like to make a hit counter that will add the count when user enter the website through their ip address. This is my code:

for views:

```
<?php echo number_format(Visitor::model()->GetAll('portal')); ?>
```

this is my model:

```
public function attributeLabels() {
    return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'web' => 'Web',
        'dtvisit' => 'Dtvisit',
        'total' => 'Total',
    );
}

public function AddVisitor($web) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $model = $this->findByAttributes(array('dtvisit' => $today, 'web' => $web));
    if (sizeof($model) > 0) {
        //update
        $model2 = $this->findByPk($model->id);
        $model2->total = (1 + $model->total);
        $model2->save();
    } else {
        //add new
        $model2 = new Visitor;
        $model2->web = $web;
        $model2->dtvisit = $today;
        $model2->total = 1;
        $model2->save();
    }
}

public function GetAll($web) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
    $model = $this->findAll(array("condition" => "web='$web'"));
    $total = 0;
    if (sizeof($model) > 0) {
        foreach ($model as $row) {
            $total+= (int) $row->total;
        }
    }
    return $total;
}
```

CUrrently, the total will add everytime I refresh or click any links on my website. How to make it add the total only when new user enter the website. Thank you

Comment: Store the last visit time and if it's more than 15 minutes update counter.

Comment: But it's more usefull to add to site Google Analitycs or something similar.

Comment: Check ip before adding to counter? Set cookies to client and check? But yeah, better use GA.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Params for passing value

```
public function GetAll($web) {
   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
   $model = $this->findAll(array("condition" => "web=':web'", 
      'params' => array(:web=$web)));
   $total = 0;
   if (sizeof($model) > 0) {
       foreach ($model as $row) {
           $total+= (int) $row->total;
       }
   }
   return $total;
}
```